# Syntax error in CShell Script

Tags: csh, shell

Write Script to read a positive integer number then it computes the following sequence:
If the number is even, halve it
If it is odd multiply it by 3 and add1

You should repeat this process until the value is 1, printing out each value and how many of these operations you performed.

```
#! bin\csh

echo "please enter any integer number :) "

set count=0

set number=$<

while($number != 1)

   if($number % 2) then

       @ number = number * 3 + 1 

   else

       @ number = number / 2

   endif

   echo " $number "

   @ count = count ++

end

echo I performed these operations $count times
```

When I run the script I get the following error:
`@: Expression Syntax.`

Comment: Please use proper formatting, a useful title for the question.

Comment: Sounds like homework or an interview question.

Comment: I dont recall csh, but isnt $count instead of @count ?

Comment: Please use correct formatting and tags. You tagged your question as "shellscript", but the syntax doesn't look like it.

Comment: no, not $ !
@ used to store expression in variable instead (set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe its $variable to obtain its value

```
$
    Obtains the value of the variable. 

@ var = $a + $x * $z
```

source  http://www.eng.hawaii.edu/Tutor/csh.html

So that would be

```
@count = $count +1
```

And the line

```
#!bin\csh
```

makes me shiver

Comment: Agreed, I would think it'd be something like #!/bin/csh

Answer (score 0):

i get correct solution :)

```
#! /bin/csh

echo "please enter any integer number :) "

set count=0

set inc=1

set number=$<

while($number != 1)

   if($number % 2) then

       @ number = $number * 3 + 1 

   else

       @ number = $number / 2

   endif

   @ count = $count + $inc

   echo " $number "


end

echo I performed these operations $count times
```